# Set a JQuery function on the button HTML declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX loading a set of sucessive pages in a main page, as I show you in the next picture:

[image]

I learned (thanks to this community!) to call other pages' content, by assigning the load() function to the onclick event of a button, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btn').click(function() {
        $('#result').load('./poi-data-no-heading.html');
      });
});
```

But what if I have one button with id="btn" on every page? The functionality of any button with that id will be the same always, because (I think) the document.ready is not triggered when I use the load() method, so it's never replaced with new functionality.

E.g. initial functionality should be navigate from page 1 to page 2, and when page 2 is loaded, the functionality should be to navigate from page 2 to page 3.

As Js developer, I would do the following:

```
<!-- In the HTML file -->
<button id="btn" onclick="loadContent()">Load</button>
<div id="result"></div>

/* In the JS file */
function loadContent(){ 
   /*the code to retrieve content*/ 
   $('#result').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/');
}
```

This way I could assign the functionality to every button, no matter what's the ID or if the document.ready is triggered. But mixing Js with JQuery is not an option... So, how do you think I should manage to do something similar with JQuery?

Thanks in advance.
P/d: Here is a useful fiddle I used to try ideas: http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/vkcug7t7/1/

Comment: That's the click handler I suggested earlier.  And no upvote. Sad face :(

Comment: OMG! Sorry! Let me see

Comment: Sounds like a use case for [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), which jQuery's `.on()` supports.

Comment: @ne1410s but you declared the function in Js and I can't mix both. Look this not-working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/vkcug7t7/3/

Comment: @ne1410s Js console: Uncaught ReferenceError: loadContent is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `on()` event from jQuery, which can listen for events on elements dynamically rendered (you can't do that with the `click()` method). So in this case you have to listen to the event on a parent element, one that doesn't change with the load method. On that button, use an HTML5 `data-*` attribute to define the id that you wish to load.

HTML:

```
<btn id="result" data-load-id="1">Load</btn>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#result', function() {
  var id_to_load = $(this).data('load-id');
  load('/url?' + id_to_load);
});
```

I've updated your fiddle : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkcug7t7/5/)

Comment: Just to be clear, the answer makes it sound like `.on()` only supports event handling in this form (event delegation). It also supports event handling without listening to the event on a child element (normal events).

Comment: @gal007 your last fiddle doesn't take into account the fact that you need to load a different content according to the button you click on. But you get the drift on event delegation :)